# Alias for perl script

Tags: perl, password, alias, bashrc, gpg

So far while surfing web I've discovered nice addition to my gpg password generator and I've decided to adjust my alias with these commands. 
Here is the code

```
gpg --gen-random 1 20 | perl -ne'print "Your password: ";s/[\x00-\x20]/chr(ord($^N)+50)/ge;s/([\x7E-\xDB])/chr(ord($^N)-93)/ge;s/([\xDC-\xFF])/chr(ord($^N)-129)/ge;print $_, "\n"'
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
alias genpass()
{
    gpg --gen-random 1 $1 | perl -ne'
    print "Your password: ";
    s/[\x00-\x20]/chr(ord($^N)+50)/ge;
    s/([\x7E-\xDB])/chr(ord($^N)-93)/ge;
    s/([\xDC-\xFF])/chr(ord($^N)-129)/ge;
    print $_, "\n"'
}
```

but error occurs when spawning new instance of bash:

```
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 18: `alias genpass()'
```

I cannot figure out how this token should be properly escaped.

Comment: You should double-quote `$1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the alias statement when you don't need it, what you're actually creating is a function, replace the word alias with function and it will work as expected.

You also don't actually need function either, you could just have the following and it will work as expected;

```
genpass()
{
    gpg --gen-random 1 $1 | perl -ne'
    print "Your password: ";
    s/[\x00-\x20]/chr(ord($^N)+50)/ge;
    s/([\x7E-\xDB])/chr(ord($^N)-93)/ge;
    s/([\xDC-\xFF])/chr(ord($^N)-129)/ge;
    print $_, "\n"'
}
```